# How do make a function execute after another one has completed successfully in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this function to create a snackbar with an action:

```
private fun setupSnackbar(view: View) {
        if (isConnected) {
            showSnackbar(view, Strings.connected, TSnackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
        } else {
            showSnackbar(view, Strings.notConnected,
            TSnackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setActionTextColor(
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.lightGreyBlue)).setAction("Connect") {
                checkBluetoothState()
                connectToProxy()
            }.show()
        }
    }

private fun checkBluetoothState() {
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
        }
}
```

I am aiming to execute connectToProxy() only after checkBluetoothState() is completed (and BT enabled).
Right now they get called at the same time. I know I would need a callback function here but I wouldn't know how to write it.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please update your code so that including checkBluetoothState() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement onActivityResult, in which you'll receive bluetooth action response, i have implemented a basic task for you, in which i'm asking for bluetooth onclick.

```
 btnBluetooth.setOnClickListener {
        val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
    }
```

You'll receive result in onActivityResult.

> i have assigned REQUEST_ENABLE_BT= 1, you can change value.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if(requestCode==REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        callYourFunction()
    }
}

private fun callYourFunction() {

    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

[image]